# no configuration file provided: not found zsh terminal

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I am attempting to set up autocompletion on the tab key in the Zsh terminal. However, whenever I press the tab key, I receive the error message "no configuration file provided: not found." Autocompletion is actually working, but for some reason, this message keeps appearing whenever I press the tab key.

Comment: Try to remove from the zsh startup files pieces and start up new zsh instances, until the problem does not occur again. My first suspect would be oh-my-zsh, so this is the first I would comment out.